# Why I need to include “ng-app” directive on each page of asp.net web page application

Tags: asp.net, .net, angularjs, web, angularjs-directive

I work on VS2012 C# Asp.net **web page** application, want to apply angular on my application , At first I  include angular files containing a file “angular.min.js” in my project and Include its reference in my master page

```
<script src=”Scripts/angular.min.js” type=”text/javascript”></script>
```

So far I know AngualrJS has several directives which perform different tasks. At first write **“ng-app”** directive in a **div or master page body tag**. It initializes an AngularJS application. It is the root element of the application allowing behavior to be modified through custom HTML tags.

I add  on master page then on child page(default.aspx) add bellow syntax:

```
<div >
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ng-model="name"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />    
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" ng-bind="name"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

The **ng-bind** directive not binds application data to the HTML view. I can not see the value of data on runtime.

when I use bellow syntax it’s work perfectly

```
<div ng-app="">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ng-model="name"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />    
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" ng-bind="name"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Both syntax are same except the  additional  ,why I need to add ng-app="" on child page ,I already add this on master page body .

if have any query please ask.Thanks in advanced ,any type of suggestion will be acceptable

[image]

Comment: If you view source in your browser, is the `ng-app` attribute there on the `body` element? Can you show us what your masterpage looks like?

Comment: master page is static and chidl pages load by ajax request? or master and chidl are assemby on server side?

Comment: Please post your javascript

Comment: Do you have a controller?

Comment: qamar thanks for your reply, yah i have a controller.